# Rotate IFC to true north

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am loading some IFC files that I can see is loading with the wrong rotation.
I assume this is something related to modern vs legacy conversion methods, but I can to know if it is possible to get the IFC loaded with the correct rotation?

If it was "just" a normal rotation around origin I could just do it with a placement transformation on load, but because the rotation is not always around origin but instead a "local origin" then the correct placement in world coordinates is hard to achieve.

Is there a way natively to load an IFC with correct placement and rotation?
I can see that the data needed is in the file `getBulkProperties2([1]....)`, but I struggle to utilize this in a good way:
[image: Screenshot from Chrome console getBulkProperties2(1.....)]

Hope you can help me get in the correct direction for fixing this.
(I know that running the file through Navisworks and selecting legacy conversion method might help, but this is not an option for us)

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Could you please provide more details? How do you know the rotation is wrong when loading the IFC model? Are you aggregating multiple models together? What were the results when you tried switching between the IFC conversion methods?

Comment: I have 2 different IFC files from 2 different native softwares (i.e. IFC structured slightly different) If opening the 2 files in Navisworks I can see them placed together and correctly, but if aggregating them together in a forge viewer 1 of the models are rotated wrongly - but I can see that the local origin is place correctly.
I have not tried to do a legacy conversion of the file on BIM360 since this would not in any case be a solid solution for us.
Does any of that make sense? Unfortunately I am not able to share the files with you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I'm afraid that without a sample dataset I won't be able to help a lot. If you cannot share the files, would you be able to perhaps create two simple IFC files (with just a box let's say) in the two native applications?